# Is there a GLfloat inside lwjgl?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Is there any alternative to `GLfloat` in `lwjgl`? There are many sources for OpenGL which use `GLfloat`. Is `GLfloat` even necessary in `lwjgl`? Can't I just replace it with a regular `float`?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, it's just a plain old Java `float`, and you don't have any need for `GLfloat` at all. All APIs in lwjgl are defined in terms of the Java primitive type `float`.

(In all C implementations that I know of, `GLfloat` is just plain old `float` as well.)

Answer (score 0):

you must use the lwjgl utilities to create a float buffer in place of the glfloat array.
located in this import.
    import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;

for example:

```
lightPos = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
lightPos.put(1).put(1).put(3).put(0).flip();
difuseLight = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
difuseLight.put(10.0f).put(10.0f).put(10.0f).put(1.0f).flip();
ambientLight = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(4);
ambientLight.put(.75f).put(.75f).put(.75f).put(1).flip();
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, ambientLight);
glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, difuseLight);
```

Comment: Is this to replace a GLfloat array?

Comment: @user1744024 yes, there are three examples in the code above lightPos, difuseLight and ambientLight. you must declare the variable as a FloatBuffer type. and you must import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils; and you can see how the float buffer is used in the code above to replace opengl's GLfloat array which looks like this in opengl example: Glfloat variable_name[] = {1, 1, 0, 1};